# Pass $index to the submit form in jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pug

I'm doing a upload image application. During uploading, it will show a loading gif. I have a few image in a page and user will press that picture to upload their image. Now, I'm using ng-repeat to show all the image out when page loaded.

Below is my html in jade:

```
                .panel-body 
                form.form-horizontal
                    .form-group(ng-repeat="runningText in runningTexts")
                        .col-md-3
                            label.control-label Image {{$index+1}}
                            .image-upload-area.label-centerleft
                                p(onclick="$('#imageFile').click()" ng-click="setNum($index)") Click me to change
                                img.loading(ng-show="isUploading[$index]" src="/img/loading.gif")    
                                img.img-responsive.clickable(ng-src="{{runningText.image != '' ? '/img/' + runningText.image : '/img/logo_d.png'}}")

                form#imageUpload(enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/admin/display/image" ng-upload="uploadDone(content)" method="post")
                    input#imageFile(type="file" name="image" onChange="$('#imageSubmit').click();return false;" style="display:none")
                    input#imageSubmit(type="submit" ng-click="isUploading[$index] = true"  style="display:none")
```

I have created an array of isUploading to act as a flag to indicate showing the uploading gif.

Below is the js:

```
    $scope.uploadDone = function(data) {
    $scope.runningTexts[imgNum].image = data.path;
    $scope.isUploading[imgNum] = false;
};

    $scope.setNum = function(index){
    imgNum = index;
}
```

img.loading will pass the $index value to the ng-click of form input so that the isUploading will be set to true.
So when the uploading is done, the flag will be set to false in js and the uploading gif will hide.

Now that seems like using my above jade coding, the $index fail to pass to "ng-click='isUploading[$index] = true'" from "img.loading", causing no uploading gif shown.

Anyone know what's wrong wif my coding?